# `make` doesn't notice modifications in a Rust module - how to better integrate Rust into the build?

Tags: makefile, rust

In a simple embedded project, i have two files `main.rs` and `module.rs`. To build the project, I use something similar to this:

```
all: main.o
    $(CC) main.o $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.rs
    $(RUSTC) $(RUSTFLAGS) -o ${@} ${<}
```

If only `module.rs` is changed, `make all` won't recompile my Rust code. How can I fix this?

---

I'm posting a suboptimal self-answer as a first step, but would love to see better ways.

Comment: The question came up in an embedded project; the project I used as a template didn't use cargo. I guess it just didn't occur to me, thanks for your input!

Comment: @Shepmaster I have edited my question slightly. I think it's open enough for your suggestion, in case you would like to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to use Make is to encode every single dependency into the Makefile. That's what gives Make the power to know what to rebuild in order to reach a goal state.

To do this for a C project, you'll often use something like the GCC command line option `-M`. This brings the compiler into the mix as it's the best tool to parse C source code and understand the dependencies between the 
files.

There is actually an equivalent switch for rustc, the Rust compiler: `--emit=dep-info`. When you run this on a source file, it will output a file with the extension `.d`, which contains an almost-Makefile-compatible list of dependencies. If you had a `main.rs` that referenced the module `foo.rs`, it would output something like:

```
main.d: main.rs foo.rs
```

With a bit of sed tweaking you can get this to play nicely. You can then include this in your Makefile:

```
main.o:
    rustc -o $@ $<

main.d: main.rs
    rustc --emit=dep-info $<
    # Add the object file as a rule
    gsed 's/:/ $(@:.d=.o):/' -i $@

-include main.d
```

Here, I've specified `main` in a few parts, but I believe that you can easily modify them into pattern rules.

Answer (score 2):

The pragmatic solution is to just use [Cargo](http://doc.crates.io/), the Rust build tool and package manager. Let it deal with dependencies (both local modules *and* other crates).

```
libbar.dylib: target/debug/libbar.dylib
    cp $< $@

.PHONY: target/debug/libbar.dylib
target/debug/libbar.dylib:
    cargo build --verbose
```

Here, I've marked the rule as `PHONY`, which says "always run this rule". I've added `--verbose` to have Cargo print out what it is doing so you can verify when things are rebuilt.

I'd recommend dropping off the `cp` step if you can and instead just use the nested path, but the copy might be needed if other things rely on the current location.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern

```
%.o: %.rs
```

is familiar from building C projects, but that's not the only way a target can be written. Specific to the setup above, this would fix the situation:

```
main.o: main.rs module.rs
    $(RUSTC) $(RUSTFLAGS) -o main.o main.rs
```

A noteworthy difference to the original code is that the names of the inputs is not really what matters for the command. We can generalize this as follows:

```
main.o: $(wildcard *.rs)
    $(RUSTC) $(RUSTFLAGS) -o ${@} ${@:.o=.rs}
```

This is a start, but it still has some downsides I couldn't get rid of:

- The `main.o:` part is hardcoded. If there are multiple top-level modules to compile, there would be code duplication
- All Rust files will be considered for all top-level modules, due to the wildcard. In other words, changing any Rust file will require a full recompilation.

Comment: Note that wildcards are often frowned upon, as your Makefile won't know to rebuild if you *delete* a source file.